# not_to change.by() is not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3

I upgraded rspec version from 2 to 3. This is one of the issues I faced:

```
Failures:

  1) Slide after .destroy(force: false) visible if .with_deleted
     Failure/Error: expect{@slide.destroy(force: false)}.to_not change(Slide.with_deleted, :count).by(1)
     NotImplementedError:
       `expect { }.not_to change { }.by()` is not supported
     # ./spec/models/slide_spec.rb:36:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

and in the [rspec's changelog](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/changelog) I can read it was never supported (oink ?!@#). At the same time there are still [some examples how to use change syntax](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers) but without `not` keyword.

So the question is how to expect no change ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Fortunately I want to expect no change (any) so I can omit `by()` part. It works just fine !

```
  expect{@slide.destroy(force: false)}.to_not change(Slide.with_deleted, :count)
```

Comment: Just for the sake of explanation, the problem is at `.by(n)`. I found this answer and didn't understand why this happen. If anyone else have the same problem: the reason is that `to_not change` means don't change at all, so `by` is wrong. Other solution could be `to change.by(0)`